# JQueryMobile: does data-transition="slideback" or alike exist?

Tags: android, jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-button

When clicking on the "home" button in my menu, I want a page transition ([data-transition="slide"](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/pages/page-transitions.html)) in the reverse move. **Does something like data-transition="slideBACK" exist ?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
$.mobile.changePage("help.html", {
    reloadPage: true,
    transition: "slide",
    reverse: true
});
```

You will get wanted effect.

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/82ke9/

To test it, go to the second page and click button **Slide back**.

Or there's a pure HTML solution:

```
<a href="#index" data-role="button"  data-direction="reverse" data-transition="slide">Reverse slide back - Variant</a>
```

Comment: Validated ! I will use the html solution. Thanks (again) Gajotres.